# Getting the "Cannot resolve the collation conflict" error from a query in a database that has only one type of format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm getting the following error :

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AI" and "Albanian_100_BIN" in the equal to operation.

From a query in a database that has only one type of format ! There is absolutly no `Albanian_100_BIN` collation in there. It can be verified with :

```
select object_name(object_id), name, collation_name
from sys.columns
where collation_name like '%_%'
```

The query is :

```
SELECT ID_ARTICLE_ECOLE FROM ARTICLE_ECOLE where UNIT_ADM  not in (select UnitAdm from  UniteAdministrative);
```

Is something wrong with the `not in` ?

---

EDIT :

it finaly worked with :

```
SELECT * FROM ARTICLE_ECOLE where UNIT_ADM not in (select UnitAdm COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI  from  UniteAdministrative) ;
```

But still, looking at the propertys of the table, there where no `Albanian_100_BIN`, maybe the in() function return this format ? That would be weird, please someone tell me it's not the case !

---

Edit :

```
update [sys].[all_columns]
set [collation_name] = 'Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS'
where name = 'UNITE_ADM' and collation_name = 'Albanian_100_BIN';
```

not allowed

Comment: Where does your  `UniteAdministrative.UnitAdm` come from? Is this on any machine or connected to a specific instance? What is the database's default collation? What is the server's default collation?

Comment: @Shnugo unitAdm comes from the same database, and the server default collation is "Latin1_General_CI_AI", and everything is "Latin1_General_CI_AI"...

Comment: What is the result on `SELECT COLUMN_NAME,COLLATION_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='UnitAdm' `

Comment: It does not show anything, if i remove the condition, the only thing i see is a bunch of Latin1_General_CI_AI

Comment: Sorry, the Table's name must be `UniteAdministrative`...

Comment: yeah also tried with the teble name

Comment: If you try this with the correct table's name it "does show nothing"???

Comment: no... this is even more strange, i'm sure it,s the correct table name...

Comment: Please try `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='UniteAdministrative'`

Comment: And please try `SELECT TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,COLLATION_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLLATION_NAME<>'Latin1_General_CI_AI'`

Comment: I can't find a way to make your querys work perfectly, but everytime i manage to see an answer, it's Latin1_General_CI_AI

Comment: Are you sure you query the right db?

Comment: Yeah, i have acces to only this one so i can't accidently touch others

Comment: Sorry, I was away... There must be something wierd... If the table 'UniteAdministrative' exists in your db, one of the statements above **must** show this. One idea could be, that this table exists only temporarily and is created with the wrong collation somewhere in a process and is dropped afterwards. Could this be true?

Comment: The table exist, it is not created through a process, it is not a view, it never gets dropped... It look like it just dosen't have any collation, is there a setting somewhere in sql server that specify what the default collation should be if there's none ?

Comment: no it dosen't make sens at all... really i'm lost here, i give up... elseway i'll go crazy

Comment: Yes, look at db's options and server's options

Comment: All the same ; Latin1_general... I don't know where that Albanian_100_bin comes from

Comment: Is the db somehow related to Albania? My last idea was an index involved. You could let SSMS create a full master db script and search the result for "albania"

Comment: An index involved ? you mean this table is related to anther ?

Comment: Constraints and sort and search indexes on string columns are bound to a collation too

Comment: i found some info in views -> SystemViews, there, i can see the god damn albanian but i can't change it, i edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

through all our comments we came closer and closer...

Please try this:

```
SELECT o.name AS ParentName,c.name AS ColumnName,c.collation_name 
FROM sys.all_columns AS c
INNER JOIN sys.objects  AS o ON c.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE collation_name = 'Albanian_100_BIN'
ORDER BY o.name,c.name
```

You cannot update `sys.all_columns`. This is a VIEW. You have to find out, which object is bound to the wrong collation and change this there.

As I told you: A collation is bound to string columns (to define their sort order), to indexes, to view's columns, to constraints...

With the query above you should find the object's name and the name of its parent object, which might be a table, or one of the above...

We'll solve this riddle ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I guess i'll never know what happen with that column collation, but at least this works :

```
SELECT * FROM ARTICLE_ECOLE 
where UNIT_ADM not in 
(
select UnitAdm COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI  from  UniteAdministrative
);
```